# System.Net.Http not found in net core 2.0 class library

Tags: .net-core

I have the following structure of my net core solution.

```
API - web api
Interfaces - class library
Implementation - class library
Models - class library
```

In the API startup.cs, I have registered the service like so:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

I have a class as such in the Implementation Project

```
using System.Net.Http;

public IHttpClientFactory ihttpClientFactory;
    public class FooImplementation: IFoo {

      public void someFooMethod(){
           // here call client to fetch data from api
           // process this data
      }

    }
```

I wanted to inject a IHttpClientFactory into this, however it is complaining that it cannot be found. How can I resolve this error? and Also, Is this the correct approach to pass IHttpClientFactory into this class library based on the project structure?

Comment: It depends on your project file. In certain cases you need an explicit package reference of https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/.

Comment: I did add the System.Net.Http via nuget into the Implementation project but didn't help. I will try the Microsoft.Extensions.Http

Comment: That resolved the issue thanks @LexLi

Answer (score 1):

You do have to check the documentation of [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) carefully, which says,

> Namespace: System.Net.Http
>
> Assembly: Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll

That's the hint on which NuGet package to use, so you should add a package reference to [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http).